# How is the linearity of a power amplifier related to its power efficiency? T

Tags: amplifier, power-amplifier, linearity

How is the linearity of a power amplifier related to its power efficiency? The two conceptsdo not seem to have much in common, or do they in this context?

Comment: audio power amplifier or RF power amplifier?

Comment: There is no context. Supply context please.

Answer (score 0):

There are huge differences in linearity and efficiency.
A class-A amplifier can be extremely linear or extremely un-linear. it is usually very inefficient because it wastes a lot of power making heat even when it is idling.
A class-D amplifier can be very linear or un-linear. It is usually very efficient.